# Qgis2Web - Why are exported labels style not displaying correctly as what has just been set?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis2web

I am using qgis2web with QGIS3.0 to make web map.

The problems I encountered were:

1. Label styles not exported correctly. (e.g. color changed, background disappeared after export etc.)
2. Zoom level - I set the Label Rendering based on scale-dependent-visibility. It displayed well in QGIS edit panel. However, it just did not want to work correctly after I exported the map into web map.

Just wondering if there is any bug in QGIS/ qgis2web.js or it was because I did not adjust some settings correctly?

This is an example:

picture(1) what I desire to see (in QGIS edit panel)
[image]

picture(2) faulty exported webmap: (result)
[image]

Scales, color, text of label background style are all wrong!

Comment: @ahmadhanb no sorry. That question was asked by me as well

Comment: Yes, I know. You are asking the same question again, which is not acceptable in this site.  Instead of re-asking the same question, please edit the first one and add details that can attract the community to help you answer the question.